# Android - Google Maps doesn't display within my application except in debugging mode

Tags: android, google-maps, debugging, export, authorization

The issue I am having is one that is mirrored in many other threads with one minor difference. I am getting this screen whenever I install the apk file received via export a signed application:
[image: Blank Display]

I have followed every one of the following stackoverflow references, but alas, nothing has helped:
-[Google Maps API V2 - always get authentication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131878/google-maps-api-v2-always-get-authentication-error)
-[Google Maps Android API v2 Authorization failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure?rq=1)
-[Google Map Android Api V2 Sample Code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216205/google-map-android-api-v2-sample-code-not-working)
-[Android - Google Map doesn't display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147767/android-google-map-doesnt-display)

**The issue is, that my map displays PERFECTLY when I am running it to the attached android phone I have plugged into my computer for debugging purposes, but when I export the apk file and install that (after uninstalling the prior of course), it does not work.**

Is there any reason why my application would work while my debugged phone is connected and the application is 'run' while said phone is attached but not when I export the apk file, and install it that way?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: did you generate a separate api key for your signed apk??

Comment: Great Question! I did not, is that a requirement for every single apk I export? Or as they share the same Keystore will that always allow me to use the same api key?

Comment: The exported APK and the debug APK are signed with different keys -- you need to obtain a new API key.

Comment: Yes it is for release mode you need a separate api key. But in debug mode you can hava many

Comment: Good grief you guys are quick at helping. That solved my problem! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate api key for your release mode. Its the same as in debug mode but you need to export the apk file again.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you either forgot to change your API key to the release key on your manifest before generating the apk or that you have the wrong release SHA1 signature to begin with. Make sure that you are using the correct API key and/or that your SHA1 release signature is correct.